# Huge memory consumption while trying to run this code

Tags: python

While trying to run this code:

```
l = 1000000
w = [1, 1]
for i in range(2, l):
    w.append(w[-1] + w[-2])
```

computer hangs on and Blue screen of death appears. The only info which I get is about MEMORY MANAGEMENT. Problem occurs in version 2.7 of Python and 3.4 as well.

Code works good for `l = 100000`.

Can someone explain me exactly why? I am using Windows 10 64-bit, Python 2.7.8 64-bit from Active Python.

EDIT:

Here is R code which works well:

```
len <- 1000000
fibvals <- numeric(len)
fibvals[1] <- 1
fibvals[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:len) { 
   fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]
}
```

Comment: Literally a bluescreen? That's not Python's fault; your computer has some serious unrelated issue.

Comment: Blue screen appears for this code only? have you tried any other program?

Comment: @Harish, yes every other program is doing well, even if I change value of 'l' variable to 100k instead of 1000k it runs well. But when I increase l from 100k to 1m I get BSOD

Comment: How much RAM do you have? How hot does your computer feel?

Comment: Windows 10 64-bit, Python 2.7.8 64-bit, 16 GB RAM. Every time I get this BSOD

Comment: Yes, this code is filling RAM *fast*. Soon your system will start to swap which may cause problems.

Comment: In addition I can say, that equivalent code written in R language is working perfect

Comment: @MarcinZdunek: The R code promptly overflowed.

Comment: Btw, Python 2.7.11 actually throws a MemoryError

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The numbers you're producing are huger than you might realize. For example, here's the size in memory of the last one:

```
>>> a, b = 1, 1
>>> for i in xrange(2, 1000000):
...     a, b = b, a+b
...
>>> sys.getsizeof(b)
92592
```

That's 92 kilobytes for one integer. All of them put together would be somewhere in the vicinity of 46-ish gigabytes, and you only have 16 gigabytes.

Your R code used 64-bit floating-point numbers, which promptly overflow to infinity at around the 1476th number.

Comment: Thank you very much, this explains all to me :)

Comment: @MarcinZdunek Dangit. Fastest gun in the west effect.

Answer (score 2):

The fibonacci numbers are HUGE. In R and other languages, integers overflow, so not that much memory is required. But in Python, integers simply don't overflow. The 1000000th fibonacci number would require terabytes of space. Once your OS uses up all the physical RAM, it'll switch over to hard disk swap. When it runs out of that, you get a kernel fault.

Comment: It's a lot of memory, but not petabytes.

Answer (score 0):

In python list take too much space in memory. try to use tuple

Example code:

```
l = 1000000
w = (1,1)
for i in xrange(2,l):
    w = w + (w[-1] + w[-2],)
```

execution of program take time, that depend on your number of cpu's and main memory.

Comment: Or, if the storage of all the number isn't actually needed, use a generator to only store the last 2 numbers

Comment: @cricket_007 awesome